# Firebase Instance ID token won't show up

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing an Android application for that I have create the token in order to send the push notification, but the token is not displaying.

At the same time there is no errors as well.

I am using firebase cloud messaging service to generate the token.

this is my app gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.visvasrithilakshan.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    // implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

this is my build gradle file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
       // classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

this is my MyFirebaseInstanceIdService.java

```
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService;

public class MyFirebaseInstanceIdService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d("myfirebaseid", "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

        // If you want to send messages to this application instance or
        // manage this apps subscriptions on the server side, send the
        // Instance ID token to your app server.
        //sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the Java code that sets up FCM?

Comment: sure let me edit the code

Comment: i have added it kindly check

Comment: Did you add this service to your manifest file? And did you added google-services.json to your project?

Comment: @DmitriyMiyai yes i have added the service what do you mean by google-services.json ?

Comment: and what about json file?

Comment: didn't get you? in the manifest only i have added the service

Comment: `Log.d` .... So, did you open the logcat panel of Android Studio?

Comment: When you are implementing FCM, you should get from Firebase Console the `google-services.json` file, which you should add to to your project.

Comment: @cricket_007 yes i double checked the log cat but the token is not there

Comment: @DmitriyMiyai if we are using fire base db only we have to do that otherwise we don't need to do that

Comment: Firebase Console is applicable to all Firebase services, I believe. Not only database. For example, Analytics would also need that JSON file

Comment: No, you need to add this file anyway, because without it your FCM not initialized

Comment: @DmitriyMiyai i have downloaded it where to put that json file?

Comment: inside `app` folder. Check this link - https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin#adding_the_json_file

Comment: For debugging purposes, use `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().instanceId.addOnCompleteListener` to get the token after it has been created.

Comment: Please refer this https://www.android4dev.com/firebase-pushnotification-android/

Comment: @DmitriyMiyai have done that though it is not working

Comment: When you debug your app, does `onTokenRefresh()` call?

Comment: `onTokenRefresh()` is for an older version of FCM. Try using the latest version which is using `onNewToken()`. With that said, implementing the services is good, but they only trigger on specific on specific times. Try calling `getToken()` on your initial activity (e.g. `MainActivity)

Answer (score 0):

Step by step:

1) Go to your root-level build.gradle file and under dependencies add this line `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'` or lower version

2) Go to you app build-gradle file and at the bottom add this line: `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

3) Go to you Firebase console download the `google-services.json` file and put it under `app` folder

4) Implement your service:

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIdService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    private static String TAG = "FirebaseInstance";
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();       
        Log.e(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);        
    }
}
```

5) Add implemented service to your manifest:

```
<service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIdService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

6) Implement your `FirebaseMessagingService` and add it to manifest:

```
<service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

That's all.

P.S. I took it from my own project and all works.

Comment: Thanks still i didn't get the token is it must to have MyFirebaseMessagingService in order to check whether token is created or not?

Comment: No, implementing the `MessagingService` is not mandatory. I checked it and I still get the token. BTW, the **IMPORTANT** thing is that `onTokenRefresh()` calls only **once** after app was just installed first time. All other launches **do not** call this method.

Answer (score 0):

```
 FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {
                if (task.isComplete()) {
                    token[0] = task.getResult();
                    Log.e("AppConstants", "onComplete: new Token got: " + token[0]);
                    Log.d("tokeb", "checking token");
                    Log.d("token", token[0]+ "V");
                    UpdateToken(token[0]); // to Server 
                }
            }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Run this code in your activity's oncreate

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
                String token = task.getResult().getToken();
                Log.i("Token", token);

            }
        });
```